# Excel Add-In Data Validation

Tags: c#, excel, validation, vsto

I am struggling to convince myself which idea is better.  Any advice would be helpful.  Here is the story:

I have an excel sheet, full of projects with each row representing a project.  I need to validate the data to check for validity.  A project is valid if and only if every data element of that project is valid too.  There are also people who work on a project.  There can be many people who work on the one project (assume that a person can only work on one project).  So for each person, i need to valid it's one set of fields, and make sure that the project it references does in fact exist.  After everything is validated, i will then push projects and people to a database.

Another thing to consider, there can be many thousands of projects.  By that virtue, there can also be many more thousands of people.

I have two validation techniques in mind:

1. Make the projects and people objects responsible for their own data validation.  This means i would have to create the objects at validation time, and then push them after they are all validated.  I dont think it's feasible to store this many objects in memory to validate and then push later.
2. Use a separate function to validate data.  The function would only look at the data, determine its type, and makes sure it meets constraints - regardless if it belongs to a person or project.  This avoids created project and people objects, but then it also means i have to make another pass over the data to create those objects.  It also means that if i add another field to a project, I have to go add another corresponding piece to the validator function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely number 1. Creating a few thousand objects will be fine. You've probably got over a gig of memory to work with, that's quite a lot :) Just keep your objects as small as possible and it'll be ok.

If it was me I wouldn't even bother writing it as a VSTO excel add-in - I'd write a separate ASP.NET web page where they could upload their excel file. From there you can parse it, validate it and insert it into your DB. Just spit out a "Failed on cell X because Y is missing" message.  If you write it as an add-in then you'll need to someone get it installed on all of the users machines, and any bug fixes will need to be pushed out and updated, which will be a PITA. I'd only go down the VSTO route if you really need to do some clever excel interaction.